# databinding with isolated storage

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, data-binding

I am developing an app, in which I am storing the settings in `IsolatedStorage`. 
I am accessing current values in my code as:

```
currentSettings = this.Resources["saveSettings"] as SaveSettings;
MessageBox.Show(currentSettings.AltitudeIndex.ToString());
```

This works fine, but when some settings are updated I need to restart the app (or reload a page) to be changes to be reflected. But I want the changes to be shown immediately without restarting the app. 
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bindable object should implements the INotifyPropertyChanged interface to be able to provide immediate UI updating.